# Understanding Adjoint Functors through the Components of the Unit/Counit

Tags: category-theory

I have been trying to wrap my head around adjoint functors. Rather than considering hom-sets, I am focusing on the ideas that I've seen presented by Bartosz Milewski in his [blog](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2016/04/18/adjunctions/) and [video series](https://youtu.be/TnV9SQGPcLY), as well as Eugenia Cheng [from The Catsters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=loOJxIOmShE) and Tai-Danae Bradley's [blog Mat3ma](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/what-is-an-adjunction-part-2).

As I understand it, given a pair $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ and $G:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{C}$, an adjunction gives a pair of natural transformations that deal with the two possible "round trips" we can take with the functors between $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$:

$$\eta:1_{C}\implies GF$$
$$\epsilon:FG\implies 1_{D}$$

My issue stems from the triangle identities. If I were to guess at the correct form for the diagrams, I would have come up with the following commutative diagram showing how the components of the natural transformations can be used to navigate between "round trips" up and down the rungs of the ladder.

[image]

However, this doesn't seem to capture the relationships the triangle identities are trying to convey. I've been staring at the commutative diagrams presented in Dr. Bradley's blog

[image]

I've been trying to follow the application of these functors and natural transformations as they act on objects, but I'm a bit stuck. I understanding using $\epsilon$ to move from $FX\to FGFX$, as I have the same in my attempt above. However, I don't see how the top left arrow between $FX$ and $FGFX$ can work. To me, taking $\eta_X$ then $F$ does get to  $FGFX$, but it would be an arrow from $X\to FGFX$ rather than from $FX$. Is there a better way to understand the triangle identities by following the arrows within/between the objects of $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$? The arrows in the functor category make some sense to me, but I think I am at the point currently where this is perhaps one level of abstraction too high. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the arrow $F \eta_X : FX \to FGFX$, it works like this: $\eta$ is a natural transformation $1_{C}\implies GF$, so applying it to $X$ gives a $\mathcal{C}$-morphism $X \to GFX$. Then applying the functor $F$ to this morphism gives a morphism $F \eta_X: FX \to FGFX$.

Comment: This made things click, thank you! So in my diagram, I'm just missing another arrow produced when $\eta$ is mapped by $F$ as though it were slid down the arrows until it sat next to $\epsilon$. I see how this would be a morphism $FX\to FGFX$. So the first of the triangle inequalities asserts that moving down from $FX$ with the unit $\eta$ then up with the counit $\epsilon$ must be the identity. It's much clearer now.